# Is there a more adequate way to remove tags?

Tags: gitlab

If I want to, let's say, delete all of 50 tags except for 3 of them, do I really have to click on all of them? Is this clicker annoyance a limitation of the free gitlab version? Is there some type of checklist on the side in the enterprise version?

[image]